# Which story had an alien who mistakes autumn/winter for Earth dying?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think he was sending a report home or communicating with another alien, and the autumn leaves falling from trees etc convinced him the Earth was dying.

Likely a short story written before 2000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "[That Strain Again](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72604)" by Charles Sheffield.

> All around us the great blight spreads. Everywhere we look the Earth
> is dying. We are contagion and bear guilt for the death of this world.
>
> .....
>
> Somewhere out there we are going to run into a planet with as big a shock in store for us as our seasons were to the Vegans.

Comment: Thank you so much! By searching for the first part of the quote you give I was able to find a Google Books preview and read the whole short story. It's not quite as I remember, but a cute little idea.

Comment: You're quite welcome, and welcome to sf stack exchange.